# Truncate decimals in string VB

Tags: vb.net

I need only 4 decimals in a string.

Dim testString As String = "78.568134"

I want to truncate testString to = "78.5681"

Comment: Find the index of the decimal point. If the length of the string is more than 4 characters past the index, perform a substring using the index + 4.

Comment: Can you provide the code.  I'm new to VB. Thanks

Comment: `dim testDecimal = 78.568134D dim testString = testDecimal.ToString("N4")`

Comment: Why do you have a number in a string to begin with? Where did it come from? If you are using numbers then they should be an appropriate numeric type, not strings. If you need a string for display purposes then you can convert from a number to a string and specify an appropriate format at that point. Jimi has demonstrated how you might do that. You should NEVER store something that is not a string, e.g. number or date, as a string unless you specifically need a string, e.g. for display or storage in a text file. If you actually need a string then you convert and format as late as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following methods based on your needs and modifications;

Try method 1)

```
Function TrimDigits(val As Double, Optional numdig As Integer = 2) As Double
Try
    Return Fix(val * 10 ^ numdig) / 10 ^ numdig
Catch ex As Exception
    Return 0
End Try
End Function
```

Try method 2)

```
truncatedNumber = Fix ( originalNumber * 100 ) / 100 'Truncate to 2 decimals.
truncatedNumber = Fix ( originalNumber * 1000 ) / 1000 'Truncate to 3 decimals.
truncatedNumber = Fix ( originalNumber * 10000 ) / 10000 'Truncate to 4 decimals.
```

Aside note
Fix() returns the integer portion of a number.

Example 01: Truncate 3.1415 to 2 decimals.

3.1415 x 100 equals 314.15
Fix(314.15) returns 314
314 / 100 equals 3.14
Example 02: Truncate 3.1415 to 3 decimals.

3.1415 x 1000 equals 3141.5
Fix(3141.5) returns 3141
3141 / 1000 equals 3.141

Int does not truncate negative numbers correctly. Int converts -8.4 to -9, and Fix converts -8.4 to -8. So Fix is the way to go

Comment: `Math.Truncate` is the way to go, given that we're not using VB6. Functions like `Fix` really only have a place in upgraded VB6 code.

Comment: Also, note that the question is about a `String`, not a `Double`. That's bad to begin with but that was the question. Your method would accept a `String` with `Option Strict Off`, but you should definitely not rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

Code to find the index of the decimal point and truncate the string if there are more than 4 characters after it.

```
Dim stringLen As Integer = testString.Length
Dim decimalOffset As Integer = testString.IndexOf(".", 0)

If decimalOffset >= 0 Then
    If stringLen > decimalOffset + 5 Then testString = testString.SubString(0, decimalOffset + 5)
End If
```

This is if you are only working with Strings. If you are working with Doubles there are other ways to do this.